# I do not save the photo in the database with CarrierWave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am using the CarrierWave gem, my problem is that it does not save me in the database, it only uploads me to the uploads folder, I have well configure it in the model as requested by the documentation. the default image is configured and it shows me perfectly. all other data is saved, except the photo. in the controller it is allowed in the parameters and it is of type string.
Add require 'carrierwave / orm / activerecord' in my environment.rb file
I don't know what the mistake could be.

My model:

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  mount_uploader  :foto,  FotoUploader
end
```

My controller:

```
def profile_params
    params.require(:profile).permit(:foto, :titulo, :matricula,
      :biografia, :telefono, :whatsapp, :provincia, :localidad,
      :direccion, :cpostal, :idiomas, :areas, :edades, :escuelas,
      :urgencias, :osociales, :tdomicilio, :presencial, :online,
      :precioconsulta, :formadepago, :cuit, :iva)
  end
```

My view(edit):

```
<div class="col-xl-4">
        <%= f.file_field :foto %>
    </div>
```

My view(show):

```
<div class="avatar">
        <%=image_tag @profile.foto.url%>
        </div>
```

My Uploader:

```
class FotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
   def default_url(*args)
  #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path('avatar.png')
  #
  #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
   end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process scale: [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
   version :thumb do
     process resize_to_fill: [150, 150]
   end

  # Add an allowlist of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  def extension_allowlist
     %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
   end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  # def filename
  #   "something.jpg" if original_filename
  # end
end
```

In terminal:

```
Started PATCH "/profiles/2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-07-25 17:19:48 -0300
Processing by ProfilesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "profile"=>{"foto"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x0000558e5e0b5d78 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20210725-126824-s6f1iw.png>, @original_filename="foto.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"profile[foto]\"; filename=\"foto.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">, "titulo"=>"Licenciada en psicologia", "matricula"=>"44986", "biografia"=>"", "telefono"=>"+543794438480", "whatsapp"=>"+543795859634", "provincia"=>"Corrientes", "localidad"=>"capital", "direccion"=>"barrio pujol mz 21 casa 2", "cpostal"=>"3400", "ninos"=>"0", "adolecentes"=>"0", "adultos"=>"0", "ancianos"=>"0", "parejas"=>"0", "grupos"=>"0", "psicoanalisis"=>"0", "cognitivo"=>"0", "integrativo"=>"0", "humanista"=>"0", "sistemico"=>"0", "es"=>"0", "en"=>"0", "pt"=>"0", "fr"=>"0", "it"=>"0", "ge"=>"0", "s1"=>"0", "s2"=>"0", "s3"=>"0", "presencial"=>"1", "online"=>"0", "osociales"=>"con reintegro", "tdomicilio"=>"No", "urgencias"=>"No", "precioconsulta"=>"", "fp1"=>"0", "fp2"=>"0", "fp3"=>"0", "cuit"=>"20323591185", "iva"=>"Monotributista"}, "commit"=>"GUARDAR", "id"=>"2"}
```

Could it be that I am not saving because the foto field generates more than 255 characters and the string field only accepts 255?

Comment: It the upload config that important. Can you post the FotoUploader code?

Comment: I just edited it with the code

Answer (score 0):

If your uploader uses `storage :file` then saving the file to the file system is the expected behaviour. There are gems that provide database storage. For example [carrierwave-postgresql](https://github.com/diogob/carrierwave-postgresql). Most people using carrierwave that don't want to store the file in the local file system, use it with a cloud storage system such as S3

Comment: yes, I am saving the files in the file system, but that is not my problem since I have configured it like this. my problem is that it does not save me anything in the database in the column that I have assigned to save me as string

Comment: Ah. OK. Could you post the `profiles` section of your schema.rb so we can see that data structure

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that ImageMagick had not been installed. problem solved